# Como popular uma sub lista de um documento com mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

É possível popular uma lista que faz referência a outra lista em um mesmo documento? Exemplo na imagem abaixo, quero popular/retornar em uma busca sempre o link de acesso referente a outra lista de links que possui as todas informações. Isso tudo faz parte do mesmo Schema.

---

[image: Schema]